# Is there any way to append the same log file instead of creating new files in python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I'm writing a log file in my python script as below:

```
logfile = 'Datalog'+currtime+'.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile,level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
logging.info(file+' is processed successfully')
```

As this job has been scheduled to run every 15 mins, its creating new log files even it has no files to process.. Is there any way to append the same log file instead of creating new files in Python 3.x? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your example, you append a variable onto the log file name: I'm assuming it's a timestamp. If you target the same filename again and again, it will be appended. See the example below from the docs:

```
import logging
LOG_FILENAME = 'example.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
```

The example above states: "If you run the script repeatedly, the additional log messages are appended to the file."

So if you change your filename to:

```
logfile = 'Datalog.log'
```

This will append to the existing file if Datalog.log exists, rather than create a new file.